# If $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n\cdot b_n=1$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n=\infty$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=0$

Tags: calculus

It's been awhile since I last touched Calculus so I'm asking for help in a really basic question. I'm trying to prove the following theorem:

> Let $a_n$ and $b_n$ be sequences so $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n\cdot b_n=1$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n=\infty$. So we get $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=0$.

I'm trying to prove this theorem by the limit definition but I can't seem to figure out how to find $\epsilon$. Is it possible to show how?

Comment: And you should search more for the indeterminate forms.

Comment: There's a very clever "proof" (it's not a formal $\epsilon-\delta$ I saw in one of the very similar posts to this: $a_n = (a_n b_n)b_n^{-1}$ so $\lim a_n = (\lim a_n b_n) \lim b_n^{-1} = 1\cdot 0 = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** For $n$ big enough, $\dfrac{1-\varepsilon}{b_n} <a_n< \dfrac{\varepsilon + 1}{b_n}$. You may also take $\varepsilon = 1$ to begin with and then $n$ big enough to get $0<a_n< \dfrac{2}{b_n}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's to the definitions:

> $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n\cdot b_n=1\Rightarrow$ Given $\varepsilon>0$, $\exists\ N_1\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|a_nb_n-1|<\varepsilon,\ \forall\ n>N_1$.

This imples,
$$|a_nb_n|<\varepsilon+1`$$

By other hand,

> $\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n=\infty\Rightarrow$ Given $A>0$ there exists $N_2$, such that $b_n>A,\ \forall n>N_2.$

Now, choosing $N=max\{N_1,N_2\}$, and for $\widetilde{\varepsilon}=\frac{\varepsilon+1}{A}$ we have

$$|a_n|=\left|\frac{a_nb_n}{b_b}\right|=\frac{|a_nb_n|}{|b_n|}<\frac{\varepsilon+1}{A}=\widetilde{\varepsilon}.$$
Thus,
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n=0.$$

Comment: Do you use $b_n=|b_n|$ and $a_nb_n=|a_nb_n|$ because $a_nb_n \to 1$ and $b_n \to \infty$ so they are definitely positive? Thanks.

Comment: @Dunkelheit Since $b_n\to\infty$ eventually it turns out positive of large $n$, $b_n$ do not need be necessarily positive. By other hand, I can't see where I suppose $a_nb_n=|a_nb_n|$, can you show me wich step I did this?

Comment: Sorry I didn't see you considered $|a_n|$, but I erroneously read only $a_n$ so I didn't get $|a_n|<\widetilde{\varepsilon}$ but just $a_n<\widetilde{\varepsilon}$ and it seemed incomplete to me, it was my mistake; so I thought you used the fact I've written in the last comment to get $|a_n|$. Do you think it is correct to make the same proof as yours but in the end use the fact that $A>0$ is arbitrary and choose $A=\frac{\varepsilon+1}{\widetilde{\varepsilon}}$? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Let's assume $\lim_na_n$ exists and is $c\neq0$. Then what about $\lim_na_nb_n$?

Answer (score 0):

The first assumption implies that for all $\varepsilon > 0$ there is $N$ such that $|a_nb_n - 1| < \varepsilon$ for $n>N$. But for all $M>0$ you have there is $K$ such that $b_n > M$ when $n>K$ by the second assumption. So once you fix $\varepsilon > 0$ and $M > 0$, both limits are valid for $n>\max\{K,N\}$, meaning that 
$$
1-\varepsilon <a_nb_n < 1+\varepsilon \quad \& \quad b_n > M, \quad \text{ for }n > \max\{K,N\}.
$$
In particular, choosing $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $1-\varepsilon > 0$ and considering that $b_n>1$ for $n$ large enough, the first inequality implies $a_n$ must be positive for $n$ large enough. Therefore, if you fix $M > 0$, you find
$$0 \leq |a_n| = a_n < \frac{1+\varepsilon}{b_n} < \frac{1+\varepsilon}{M}, \quad \text{for } n > \max\{K,N\},$$
which implies your limit.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $\lim a_n \neq 0$. That is, there is some $a^* \neq 0 \in \mathbb{R}$ s. th. for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $N_{\varepsilon}$ s. th $|a^* - a_n| < \varepsilon$ for $ n > N_{\varepsilon}$. In particular $|a_n| > c > 0$ for some $c$.

Since $b_n \rightarrow \infty$ (i.e. for any $B \in \mathbb{N}$ there is $n_B$ s. th $b_n > B$ for $n > n_B$), consider the following argument for the product:

Let $B \in \mathbb{N}$ and $c > 0$ be arbitrary. Take $n_1$ s. th $b_n > N$ for all $n > n_1$. Take $n_2$ s. th. $|a_n| > c > 0$  for any $n > n_2$. Then for any $n > \max\{n_1, n_2\}$ we have:

$$ |a_n b_n| > c N $$

Since N can be chosen arbitrarily large, if follows that $\lim |a_n b_n| = \infty$. This is a contradiction, hence a cannot converge to any number other then $0$.

This still does not cover the case where $a_n$ doesn't converge at all. That is an exercise for you.